# Bottle conditioning / carbonation temperature

Tags: carbonation, bottle-conditioning, temperature-control

Yesterday i bottled my first brew. I put the bottles in a box in my room. There is a thermometer inside the box, it reads 25°C. I've read before that the it should be in 18°C - 24°C range.

Will 25°C affect taste and/or flavor? Although i believe i gave enough room for CO2, i don't want to have bottle bombs.

What can i do to lower the temperature? I thought about putting the bottles in a bucket and filling the bucket with cold tap water. Will this work? Do you have any other ideas?

I brewed a Mr. Beer Aztec Mexican Cerveza. The fermentation temperature was around 23°C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beer needs to be warmer when you bottle condition. This allows the yeast to work hard at getting the priming sugar into CO2. However, too warm and the beer will stale faster.

I recommend moving the box to a cooler area of the house (like a cupboard that is not against a wall that gets direct sunlight). DO NOT COOL THE BEER! Leave it for two weeks, then put a bottle in the fridge to chill and see if it carbonated enough.

Otherwise just hide the beers under your bed for the next two weeks. :)